# How to select entire rows based on distinct columns

Tags: sql, pyspark, apache-spark-sql, hiveql

I am doing this in spark

```
cityId  PhysicalAddress      EmailAddress         ..many other columns of other meta info...   
1       b st                 something@email.com   
1       b st                 something@email.com   <- some rows can be entirely duplicates
1       a avenue             random@gmail.com
2       c square             anything@yahoo.com
2       d blvd               d@d.com
```

There is no primary key on this table and I want to grab one random row based on each distinct cityId

e.g. This is a correct answer

```
cityId  PhysicalAddress      EmailAddress        ..many other columns 
1       b st                 something@email.com   
2       c square             anything@yahoo.com
```

e.g. this is also an correct answer

```
cityId  PhysicalAddress      EmailAddress       ..many other columns 
1       a avenue             random@gmail.com
2       c square             anything@yahoo.com
```

One way that comes to mind is to use a `group by`. However, that requires me to use an aggregate function on the other column. (such as min()). Whereas, I just want to pull out an entire row (doesn't matter which one).

Answer (score 0):

```
;WITH CTE AS
(
   SELECT *, ROW_NUMBER() OVER(PARTITION BY cityId ORDER BY cityId) AS RN
   FROM [TABLE_NAME]
) SELECT * FROM CTE WHERE RN = 1
```

Answer (score 0):

I have Sql Server 2008 R2, but have tried to find ways which would work on other DBMS.

```
create table contacts( cityId int, PhysicalAddress varchar(max), EmailAddress varchar(max) )

delete contacts
insert contacts( cityId, PhysicalAddress, EmailAddress )    /** ..many other columns of other meta info...  */  
values 
   ( 1, 'b st', 'something@email.com' )  
 , ( 1, 'b st', 'something@email.com' )                     /* some rows can be entirely duplicates */
 , ( 1, 'a avenue', 'random@gmail.com' )
 , ( 2, 'c square', 'anything@yahoo.com' )
 , ( 2, 'd blvd', 'd@d.com' )
 , ( 3, 'e circuit', 'e@e.com' )

-- using row_number()

with c as (
      select *, row_number() over (partition by cityId order by cityId) as seqnum
      from contacts
     )
    select * from c
    where seqnum = 1;


-- Add a new identity column

alter table contacts
    add id int identity(1,1)

select * from contacts where id in (select min(id) from contacts group by cityID)

-- Variation: Create a copy into a temp table and add an identity column
-- Note: It may not be possible to modify original table

select * into #contacts from contacts
alter table #contacts
    add id int identity(1,1)
select * from #contacts where id in (select min(id) from #contacts group by cityID)
```

I also tried using a computed column using `newid()` but my excitement was short-lived because when you join the table to itself or use a subquery on that table, the computed column is recalculated for each `SELECT`, so that didn't work. You can't make that computed column `PERSISTED` - that is not allowed for non-deterministic expressions like `newid()` which returns something different each time it is called on a given row.